# Is language a technology or is technology a language?

Tags: meaning

Is spoken/written language a technology or is technology a language?

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: Written language is a technology, i.e artificial. Spoken language is a part of human evolution, i.e, natural.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is spoken language any association of something with sound? (Is thunder part of the natural language of Earth? If not then isn't any association part of  formal language? ... a technology even at the stage of only being spoken?)

Comment: This all depends on your definitions for "language" and "technology", and they're all over the map.

Comment: This isn’t a question about English or its usage – it’s more a question of philosophy. There is a stack for that ([philosophy.se]), but I don’t frequent it, so I don’t know if this question would be considered on topic there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I'm looking for usage, not debate.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you. If that's the case then there's no answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler I doubt your claim that spoken language is natural. If it were, all humans should speak the same language. That I understand English and Spanish but not Chinese or German creates a chicken and egg problem. I learned these languages by being exposed to them, but how would one who has never been exposed to them learn them? I think it's fair to say that the very earliest forms of spoken language were probably natural, but the spoken languages we have today almost certainly are not the least bit natural.

Comment: @RMac (Why would natural selection give the same result every time?)

Comment: The definition of [technology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/technology) is **The application of scientific knowledge for practical purposes**. Natural language (and the vast majority of languages are "natural") have not been designed using scientific knowledge so cannot be called technologies. Esperanto is an artificial language based on a knowledge of languages and linguistics so could be considered a technology but very few, if any, others can be.

Comment: @RMac *Language* is natural/inherent, but any *specific* language has to be learned. For obvious reasons, we can't carry out the experiment of bringing up infants with no exposure to language to find out whether they develop a language in a generation or two, but I think it is generally assumed that they would.

Comment: But I don't see how technology could be considered a language (with a few exceptions like the design of user interfaces or programming languages).

Comment: When somebody uses the word *technology* in everyday communication, it is pretty certain that he does not intend it to encompass languages. It is conceivable that, in the context of some theoretical (e.g. philosophical) argument, it might be illuminating to regard languages as a form of technology, but anybody who wanted to use the word that way would need, as a part of the argument, to explain the reasons for so using it.

Comment: @JamesRandom Perhaps it's because technology is a specific set of [technical] distinctions ... a nomenclature.

Answer (score 1):

technology means: teckne from the Greek for art ("Techne" is a term, etymologically derived from the Greek word τέχνη, which is art or craft)  and logos ( λόγος,in Greek, which has many translations, such as word, reason or plan. It is very complicated by came to mean the logic of an argument.

[logic of an argument, among others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logos)

I do not think that language produced by humans is a technology, except in reference to the Greek. I see nothing artificial about written language....It is an object created by human beings.

Jacques Lacan said that humans are speaking beings, être parlants. And we humans are the only ones who speak, though other mammals communicate through what are essentially codes. They cannot comment on their thoughts. They don't have meta capacity: they can signal, "I am hungry" they cannot comment on that hunger.

We, humans, are the only ones who have access to what the French linguist Ferdinand de Saussure called the double articulation of language. That means the picture of the apple I have in my mind or the word apple I speak is not an actual apple. And it's this double articulation that makes it possible to create so many language acts (speech and writing) and gives humans the capacity to produce meta-language (commenting on the comment, as it were).

Humans produced (or spoke) language first (speech), then found a way to write/record messages in their languages and lastly, chronology-wise, found a way to create mathematical language(s) and lastly (and somewhat recently in historical terms) computer/computing languages, but even those come from human beings, though we often forget that.

Generally speaking, people to tend to view natural languages (what you speak) as "natural" and written languages as more contrived. I would argue that written languages cannot exist or cannot have existed without human speech, or humans who speak/spoke language(s). Human speech preceded writing systems intended to record it.

So, no human language is most definitely not "a technology", unless one sees it as the art of the word. Humans use their language to create technology, technology as we understand all this crap (machine languages and machines that do things for us) we are dealing with today. This is really rather intuitive, I would think.

Here is the scoop on the first written languages:

> [first written languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_first_written_accounts)

Comment: Perhaps the capacity to express thoughts through vocal utterance is a natural capacity of humans, but the languages we have today are certainly human inventions. The vocabularies and grammars of those language are not known to us unless taught.

Comment: @RMac "[...] but the languages we have today are certainly human inventions?? What does that even mean? Anyway, I never said the invented languages (computer, math, etc.) are not human inventions, did I? I said that written language is not technology. The distinction is natural languages (French, Malay, German) versus other languages such machine, computing and mathematical languages. Of course, those were created ("invented") by humans.

Comment: @Lambie "I see nothing artificial about written language....It is an object created by human beings." What does artificial mean if not invention?  I have to ask if physics is a technology? It seems to be, so why wouldn't any set of distinctions be a technology?

In other words, is technology only the technique or also the terminology?